# What conditional independence theorem is being used here

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In stanford's [machine learning lecture 1](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes1.pdf), linear regression is defined on page 11, section 3 as:

For $i = 1, \ldots, m$, $y^{(i)} = \theta^T x^{(i)} + \epsilon^{(i)}$, where
$\epsilon^{(i)}$ are IID normal ($x^{(i)}$ are random explanatory variables).

On the bottom page 12 it then goes on to say:

> Note that by the independence assumption on the $\epsilon^{(i)}$'s (and hence also the
>   $y^{(i)}$'s given the $x^{(i)}$'s))

What theorem is it using here to justify this? Is it true that $Z_i = f (X_i, Y_i)$ where $f$ is Borel-measurable, $Y_i$ are independent,
then $Z_i$ are conditionally independent given $X_i$? Or is it using something else? A proof or reference to one would be great too.

Comment: Usually, it's assumed that $\epsilon$-s are i.i.d. conditional on $x$-s e.g. $\epsilon|x\sim N(0,\sigma^2 I)$.

Anyway, you need more assumptions to justify the claim, e.g. independence of $x$'s and $\epsilon$-s...

Comment: @d.k.o. Is it any easier in that case?

Comment: It seems that the author (of these notes) does not properly state assumptions about $\epsilon$-s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Counterexample**: Let $n=2$ and $\theta=1$; $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2\sim_{i.i.d}\text{Bernoulli}(0.5)$. Take $x_1=\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1$, and $x_2=\epsilon_1-\epsilon_2$. Then

$$y_1=\epsilon_2\text{; }y_2=\epsilon_1$$

and

$$\frac{1}{2}=P\{y_1=0,y_2=0|x_1=0,x_2=0\}$$
$$\ne P\{y_1=0|x_1=0,x_2=0\}P\{y_2=0|x_1=0,x_2=0\}=\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{2}$$

So, $y$-s are not conditionally independent.

Answer (score 1):

Since $Y^i = \theta^T X^i + E^i$, by the substitution principle  $$(Y^i \mid X^i =x^i) = \theta^T x^i + E^i,$$ where $x^i$ is a  constant. Since the $E^i$ are independent, the $Y^i$ are conditionally independent.

More explicitly, conditional pairwise independence holds because

\begin{align}
P(Y^i \in{A_i}, Y^j \in{A_j}\mid X^i=x^i,X^j=x^j) &= P( E^i  \in {A_i - \theta^T x^i }, E^j \in {A_j-\theta^T x^j})\\ &=P( E^i  \in {A_i - \theta^T x^i }) P( E^j \in {A_j-\theta^T x^j}). 
\end{align}

Conditional independence holds as well, by a similar reasoning.

Comment: Is it required that $X_1,...,X_m,E_1,...,E_m$ are jointly independent here? I suppose that's a reasonable assumption, also equality is over $P_{X_1,...,X_m}$ a.s. right?

Comment: It is necessary that $E_i$ is independent of $X_i$. equality is  $P_{X_1,...,X_m,E_1,\ldots E_m}$ a.s.

Comment: Which steps requires $E_i$s in the a.s. equality? Aren't both the replacement rule and removing the conditional $X_i$ a.s.? btw I would accept your answer too but can only accept one.